# Prove that for all natural numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ that $gcd(x,y)gcd(z,w) | gcd(xz,yw)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that for all natural numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ that  $gcd(x,y)gcd(z,w) | gcd(xz,yw)$. I established a prime factorization product for each variable and I've tried using GCD's via prime factorizations to prove this but I get stuck when I multiply $gcd(x,y) \times gcd(z,w)$ and I'm not sure what to do with $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}{p_i^{min(a_i, b_i) + min(c_i, d_i)}}$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are three key facts: 
First, $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$ as it is a common divisor. 
Second, if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|\gcd(b,c)$, by definition of the greatest common divisor. 
Third, if $a|b$ and $c|d$ then $ac|bd$, for if $b=ax$ and $d=cy$ , we have $bd=ac(xy).$

Notice that $\gcd(x,y)$ divides $x$ and $y$. 
Similarly, $\gcd(z,w)$ divides $z$ and $w$.

Hence, $\gcd(x,y)\gcd(z,w)$ divides $xz$ and $yw$. This implies $\gcd(x,y)\gcd(z,w)|\gcd(xz,yw).$

As for your particular approach, it suffices to observe that the exponent of $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $xz$ is $a_i+c_i$. In particular, this is at least $\min(a_i,b_i)+\min(c_i,d_i)$. This implies $$ \gcd(x,y)\gcd(z,w)=\prod_{j=1}^\infty p_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)+\min(c_i,d_i)}|\prod_{j=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i+c_i}=xz.$$
Similarly, $\gcd(x,y)\gcd(z,w)$ divides $yw$.